# PHP can't get file from an HTML form

Tags: php, html

I can't pass an image from an HTML form to PHP in order to upload it on my server, here's the PHP code

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
include_once('config.php'); //db configuration
if (isset($_FILES['image'])){
    echo "I have the image";
}
else{
    echo "Image not loaded";
}}
```

And here's the html form:

```
<form method="post" action="edit_profile.php">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group mb-30">
    <label class="control-label mb-10 text-left">Edit profile image</label>
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
        <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
        <span class="input-group-addon fileupload btn btn-info btn-anim btn-file"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <span class="fileinput-new btn-text">Select file</span> <span class="fileinput-exists btn-text">Edit</span>
        <input type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" name="image" /> <!-- INPUT ELEMENT -->
        </span> <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-danger btn-anim fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i><span class="btn-text">Remove</span></a> 
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-anim" id="submitInfo"><i class="icon-rocket"></i><span class="btn-text">Confirm</span></button>
</div>
```

I've already checked that the 'name' attribute of `"<input type="file" />` and also the configuration file php.ini, I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: try using in form tag enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: You could have simply read up on that, you know ... http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

In the form specify the ctype like

```
<form method="post" action="edit_profile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```